# send matlab data from matlab executable to matlab workspace

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a matlab compiled Windows executable (my_matlab_app.exe)
I would like to send matlab data (arrays of numbers) directly from this executable to the MATLAB application workspace itself.

Is this possible?

It would be similar to this [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/535390/Write-to-Excel-Sheet-through-Matlab]

Answer (score 2):

For small amounts of data, you can do something like this:

```
matlab /r "x=2;myscript"
```

This starts an instance of MATLAB, sets the value of `x` to `2`, and then runs `myscript` which can use the value of x.  For larger data sets, this is probably not practical...I would recommend saving the data in your compiled application to a .mat file ( `myfile.mat`) file, and then using the command line syntax to load it:

```
matlab /r "x = load myfile.mat"
```

You can execute these commands from your compiled application as system calls:

```
result = system ('matlab /r "x = load myfile.mat"')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't explain myself well enough.  I would like to send the dynamic internal data (from within my compiled matlab executable) to the actual MATLAB commercial application itself.